# the document.querySelector() can selects the attributes also?

Tags: javascript, html, selector

I recently saw a code voucher that surprised me a bit and I would really like to understand. Can the document.querySelector() take a parameter, an attribute to make selections :

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-value]')
```

```html
 <span data-tab-value="#tab_1">Tab-1</span>
```

I would also like to know why the attribute name is enclosed in brackets.

Comment: [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: What @Andy said. The short answer is 'Yes'. An attribute selector is a valid argument for `.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: a syntax choice

Comment: You can use whatever selector is valid in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**document.querySelector** is just like CSS selectors

It can even select elements with attributes like:

```
document.querySelector("input[name]") // <input name>; input which has attribute name
document.querySelector("input[type=number]") // <input type='number'>; input whose attribute type's value is number
```